# Disabling scrolling in a app in Samsung S5 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, samsung-mobile

I have a task of disable scroll on clicking a button and again enable it on another button click.I have searched a lot in internet and got some answer as below which are working in every devices except in samsung s5.

One method was adding overflow:hidden to the body tag there by disabling scroll

Another is by adding the following js function,

```
$('#element').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
})
```

But both didnt work in samsung s5 , Give me any link or solution for this bug

Comment: If you dont know answer ,then upvote my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer for this question . You can use

JS

```
$("#popupMenu").delegate('.ui-content', 'touchmove', false);
```